# aapt: Do not skip (null) files when packaging

Tags: python, android, aapt

I am developing an Android application that uses a number of python scripts in `res/raw` that are deployed via SL4A and included in the app's APK. As the scripts make use of python packages, their directories contain a number of 0byte sized `__init__.py` files that are necessary for python to recognize the directories as packages.
My problem is that `aapt` skips those files during packaging, thus preventing the scripts from working on the device/emulator, as the modules are not found by the interpreter:

```
[aapt] Creating full resource package...
 [null]     (skipping (null) file '/home/user/app/res/raw/pypackage/__init__.py')
```

Is there a way to tell `aapt` to include the files nevertheless, or do I have to pad the files manually to make them >0kb sized? I already looked at the `aapt` command-line options but I didn't find anything.

Comment: The AssetManager might be a better solution to this than raw resources. Especially since it sounds like you need directory structure and resources don't support such. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your only problem you can just add a comment '**#**' inside the `__init__.py` files.
If you find more problems as the directory structure you can use a tar or zip and expand it after APK installation.

Comment: As it turns out, `(null)` files are not files with 0byte size, but files whose name starts with an underscore. So the only way to include them in the apk without changing their name is indeed to put them into a zip file and extract that at runtime.